# Can Braintree charge a card without billing information?

Tags: paypal, payment, braintree

I have integrated Braintree into my API and have it currently accepting payments under the sandbox mode. I have noticed that the Drop In UI for braintree does not include an area to put customer billing information. Is a customers name and other personal information similar to that required to make a credit card charge through braintree subscriptions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Billing address information is not required to charge a credit card for a normal transaction or a subscription unless [you have turned on the address verification system](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/guides/fraud-tools/avs-cvv).